# need to get all addresses for users. already have query, but can't left join address properly

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to extract all my customer info from the db. **I need to get all addresses for a user.**

I have a user table and address table. The address table holds 0-many addresses for each user. I need all of the addresses for each user joined to my existing query and **I don't mind the repeated user info per address**.

So far I have this query which returns all customer data, joined with the region table to get the currency name, and left joined with orders to get total number of shipped orders for that user.

```
SELECT ( CASE
       WHEN u.password IS NULL THEN 'GUEST'
       ELSE 'CUSTOMER'
     END )                                 AS STATUS,
   u.date_created                          AS DateCreated,
   u.NAME                                  AS UserName,
   u.password                              AS Password,
   u.email                                 AS Email,
   r.token                                 AS Currency,
   Cast(u.balance / 100 AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS Balance,
   Count(o.user_id)                        AS TotalShippedOrders
FROM   [db].[user] u
   INNER JOIN [db].[region] r
           ON r.currency_id = u.balance_currency
   LEFT JOIN [db].[order] o
          ON o.user_id = u.id
             AND o.status = 'shipped'
 GROUP  BY u.id,
      u.date_created,
      u.NAME,
      u.password,
      u.email,
      r.token,
      u.balance
ORDER  BY TotalShippedOrders DESC;
```

I tried to LEFT JOIN the address table, but it through off the TotalShippedOrders count.

```
SELECT ( CASE
       WHEN u.password IS NULL THEN 'GUEST'
       ELSE 'CUSTOMER'
     END )                                 AS STATUS,
   u.date_created                          AS DateCreated,
   u.NAME                                  AS UserName,
   u.password                              AS Password,
   u.email                                 AS Email,
   r.token                                 AS Currency,
   Cast(u.balance / 100 AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS Balance,
   Count(o.user_id)                        AS TotalShippedOrders, 
   a.*
FROM   [db].[user] u
   INNER JOIN [db].[region] r
           ON r.currency_id = u.balance_currency
   LEFT JOIN [db].[order] o
          ON o.user_id = u.id
             AND o.status = 'shipped'
   LEFT JOIN [db].[address] a
          ON a.user_id = u.id
 GROUP  BY u.id,
      u.date_created,
      u.NAME,
      u.password,
      u.email,
      r.token,
      u.balance
ORDER  BY TotalShippedOrders DESC;
```

Can someone point me in a direction on how to formulate this part of my query? Thanks!

**EDIT:** I added DISTINCT to the Count and that seemed to have fixed the issue, but I don't think it's returning all user/address combinations yet. This simple query returns more rows than the one above:

```
select * from [db].[user] u
LEFT JOIN [db].[address] a ON a.user_id = u.id 
order by u.id
```

I am expecting to see each row to have user info and one address. If a user has more than one address, it will have that many rows with the same user info but different addresses. Some users do not have addresses, that's why I did a LEFT JOIN.

Can someone point out where I'm going wrong with the query's logic? Thanks!

Comment: maybe replace Count(o.user_id)  with Count(distinct o.user_id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem would indicate that you have more than one address per user.  Perhaps you want only one address, such as the most recent address.  If so, something like this should work:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM [db].[user] u INNER JOIN
     [db].[region] r
     ON r.currency_id = u.balance_currency LEFT JOIN
     [db].[order] o
     ON o.user_id = u.id AND o.status = 'shipped' LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT a.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.user_id ORDER BY a.id DESC) as seqnum
      FROM [db].[address] a
     ) a
     ON a.user_id = u.id AND a.seqnum = 1
. . .
```

It uses the address with the largest id in the address table.

EDIT:

If you need all addresses, then you need to do the join after the aggregation:

```
with t as (
      <your query here with "u.id as user_id" in the select
     )
select t.*, a.*
from t left join
     addresses a
     on t.user_id = a.user_id;
```

Comment: I need all addresses. Please see edit above and thanks for the input!

Comment: Thank you so much! Why do you need to do the join after the aggregation function? What did the 2nd left join do to the aggregate function?